# How to directly convert Data Snapshot to object?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

There is a code in firebase DocumentSnapshot that converts the data to an object like

```
Class object = documentSnapshot.toObject(Class.class);
```

**Is there any code that makes the same thing using DataSnapshot instead of Document Snaphot?**
I'm using Firebase RealtimeDatabase for my Aplication

Comment: Check the documentation. Use getValue(): https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_and_write_data

Comment: Thanks, now i recreate the object myself

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of Firestore's `DocumentSnapshot.toObject` method in Realtime Database is `DataSnapshot.getValue`.

So:

```
Class object = dataSnapshot.getValue(Class.class);
```